# How to calculate vmrss from elf file

Tags: memory, elf

I am working on an embedded system with limited memory. I want to find a way to calculate how much memory will be used when an elf file is running by analyzing it.

I hope the result is close to **vmrss**, which I can use `cat /proc/pid/status` to get. The memory changes every moment when running. so a closer result or lower bound is also useful.

Assuming that there is no dynamic memory(like through malloc) or mapped memory(through mmap).

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying assumptions:

1. you don't use shared libraries
2. you don't run multiple instances of your ELF binary
3. you don't use swap
4. your binary accesses all of its code and data
5. there is no significant `malloc` or `mmap` usage

With above assumptions, you can look at `readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD`, and simply add together the `PT_LOAD` segment sizes for an upper bound on RSS.

If you do use shared libraries, you'll need to add their `PT_LOAD` segments as well. But if they are used by more than one binary, then total system memory consumed will be less than the total of RSS for each process. Same goes for violating assumption 2.

Violating assumptions 3 and 4 will reduce observed RSS, while violating 5 will increase it.

Comment: I can only find LOAD. and the sum is far  from VmRss

Comment: @fanux If you hope to receive help, you'll have to provide more details than that. Edit your question with additional info: which of the assumptions are wrong, what you find in your `LOAD` segments, how it compares to `VmRss`, etc. etc.